# Count number of occurrence

Tags: c#

I am working on this code in which it can find the word in the Web Browser coming from the list. I want to count the number of occurrence and insert it into another column in the database before replacing those words into asterisk. Is there any solution?

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(txbAdress.Text);
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
}

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder(doc2.body.outerHTML);


    string query;
    query = @"select Word from ListWords";

    List<string> words = new List<string>();

    DataSet ds;
    DataRow drow;

    ds = DatabaseConnection.Connection1(query);
    int index, total;

    total = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

    string current_word;

    for (index = 0; index < total; index++ )
    {
        drow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[index];
        current_word = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();

        words.Add(current_word);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(query);


    Console.WriteLine("array:" + words);
    foreach (String key in words)
    {   
        int len = key.Length;
        string replace = "";

        for ( index = 0; index < len; index++)
        {
            replace += "*";
        }

        html.Replace(key, replace);
        //count++;
    }

    //Console.WriteLine("Total number of words: " + count);


    doc2.body.innerHTML = html.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is your code working/not working? What is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to use regular expression to do counting and replacing:

```
Dictionary<string,int> counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var word in words)
{
    var matches = Regex.Matches(html, $@"\b{word}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    counts.Add(word, matches.Count);
    html = Regex.Replace(html, $@"\b{word}\b", "".PadLeft(word.Length, '*'), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}

foreach (var kv in counts)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{kv.Key}:{kv.Value}");
}
Console.WriteLine(html);
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helpful.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

namespace CountNumberTest
{
    public class WebBrowserReplaceHtmlFromDatabaseTest
    {
        private const string BaseAddress = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52572969/count-number-of-occurrence";

        private readonly ITestOutputHelper Output;
        private static readonly HttpClient StaticHttpComponent = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress)
        };

        public WebBrowserReplaceHtmlFromDatabaseTest(ITestOutputHelper output)
        {
            this.Output = output;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task When_GetHtmlBodyFromWebPage_Then_ReplaceAllWordInHtml()
        {
            var replaceWordCollection = new[] { "html", "I", "in", "on" };
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"{BaseAddress}");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await StaticHttpComponent.SendAsync(request);

            Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);

            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            Assert.NotEqual(0, buffer.Length);

            foreach (string word in replaceWordCollection)
            {
                int len = word.Length;

                int countOccurrence = Regex.Matches(buffer.ToString(), word).Count;
                var replaceWord = new string('*', len);

                Output.WriteLine($"{word} - occurred: {countOccurrence}");
                buffer.Replace(word, replaceWord);
            }

            string html = buffer.ToString();
            foreach (string word in replaceWordCollection)
                Assert.DoesNotContain(word, html);

            Output.WriteLine(html);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How/why would this be useful? What did you change and why? Please read [answer], code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, code only answers are perfectly fine. I don't mean this is an answer but that shouldn't be a reason to down vote either (especially if you are not providing anything better).

Comment: @CetinBasoz It's a perfect reason for downvoting if you have to go through the two codes to determine the differences. I would agree with you if it was a line or two

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, no you don't have to. It is obvious at a glance.

Comment: @CetinBasoz It can be obvious for me or you, not for a starter. Specially when the answerer adds irrelevent stuff like xUnit dependencies

Comment: @CetinBasoz I didn't downvote yours, I didn't vote on yours at all